# Fixed-width column table force expand on container

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, overflow

Apparently a classic problem, but the "solutions" I've found haven't worked, including various other questions on SO.

If my table is wider than its container, I want my table cell width to remain fixed and not be resized to fit the container.

Reproducible HTML (`<td>`s generated with PHP):

```
<html>
  <head></head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <?php for($i=0;$i<15;$i++) { 
           echo "<td style='width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;'>".($i+1)."</td>"; 
        } ?>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div style='background:chartreuse;width:150px'>This is 150px wide.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I've tried:

- `table-layout:fixed`
- `span` container with `display:inline-block` set
- `div` container with inline block

It seems there should be an easy way to make the previous code generate a table that overflows the body.

Can someone help?

*Edit*

It may not be clear from my previous wording, but I want to specify column width myself.

I'm trying to do this without specifying an explicit width for the table. Only the TDs will force the table wider, which (should?) force the container wider.

Also, the inline CSS is there for example purposes only.

Comment: table-layout:fixed will solve the issue. Remove the inline styling you give for the td. You are specifying a width. When you don't specify the width for the td, the tds get resized according to the content and giving table-layout fixed will not resize to fit the content

Comment: @Bala - see edit.  I want `<td>`s to be a set width. If I do not set the width on the `<td>`s, then the problem is nullified.

Comment: You can share the generate HTML code or lemme know if its available online to check.

Comment: Future readers of this post: source HTML from my question has been reproduced in my answer below with working solution (thanks again Bala).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div style="margin: 0pt auto; width: 980px;">
  <div style="500px;overflow:scroll">
    <table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
          <td style="width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;">This is 150px wide.</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="background:chartreuse;width:150px">This is 150px wide.</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: BAM there it was thanks. I knew there was an easy solution :p  I was missing `width:100%`.  Cheers!  My reproducible code is below, with the correct CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Using my HTML in my question, here's the correct markup, compliments of @Bala.

```
<html>

  <head></head>

  <body>
    <table style='table-layout:fixed;width:100%'>
      <tr>
        <?php for($i=0;$i<15;$i++) { echo "<td style='width:150px;border-right:1px solid black;'>".($i+1)."</td>"; } ?>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div style='background:chartreuse;width:150px'>This is 150px wide.</div>
  </body>

</html>
```